# urllib2 request returns a different page about 1 in 5 times

Tags: python, request, urllib2, user-agent

```
import urllib2

req = urllib2.Request('http://www.amazon.com/Sweet-Virgin-Organic-Coconut-13-5oz/dp/B00Q5CIL4Y', headers={ 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0' })

html = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
print len(html)
```

That's the smallest example I can make. If you run that then ~1 in 5 times the length of the response will be 5769, and the other times it will be a normal usable response.

Whats up with this?

edit:

incorrect response: http://pastebin.com/d7zdy0uv

Comment: Did you print out the HTML to look at the difference?

Comment: I strongly suggest using [`requests`](http://python-requests.org) instead. It makes working with web sites **so** much easier, including the ability to analyze the headers directly: `r = requests.get(url, headers=headers); print r.headers`.

Comment: I was originally having the issue with Scrapy, I just spent the last hour breaking the issue down into this one simple sample. I've looked at the difference in the html many times. The correct response is similar to the source if you navigate to the site using chrome, the incorrect response is here: http://pastebin.com/d7zdy0uv

Comment: @MattDMo: `requests` is good, but `r = urllib2.urlopen(req); print r.headers` does the job too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the content of the short responses, this becomes much easier to answer. Amazon suspects you're doing automated scraping of its site, and has served you a CAPTCHA that, if you were a human using a browser, you could solve.

I'm slightly surprised it only hits you one in five requests, though, rather than either always or never.

As it says in Amazon's response, consider using their APIs instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it must be an issue on your side- I've run it ~50 times and I'm getting ~490000 or so every time.

You are being rate limited.

Check the length of data, when you detect a short packet you need to wait a period until you are not rate limited.  (You'll have to figure out what rate is sustainable)

Comment: I'm running it on a Ubuntu server. I can't use requests because I found the problem using Scrapy's default (downloader?). I shouldn't have to change the middleware, the default Scrapy tools should work fine.